# Problemas en la terminal de VSC(Se ejecuta una terminal de Python vacía en vez de la terminal por defecto de VSC)

Tags: python, vscode

Yo he estado utilizando Visual Studio Code desde hace ya un buen tiempo y nunca me había dado ningún tipo de problema, pero de un día para otro ahora de solo abrir VSC se me abren varias terminales de Python y cuando voy a ejecutar un proyecto en vez de ejecutarse en la terminal por defecto lo que pasa es que se abre una terminal de Python vacía. No tengo ni idea de que puede estar ocasionándolo, ya reinstale Python y instale la ultima versión de VSC(1.80.1)

Esto pasa cuando lo abro:[image]
Y esto cuando ejecuto algo:[image]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.